# Sudo invoked in a python program doesn't work

Tags: python, bash, chown, sudoers

This is quite a specific question. In my program, I am using a particular file to run with a sudo-command, which I call CHOWN.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "usb"] #first argument is usb
then 
    chown eng:eng /mnt/usb
else
    ...
```

When I call the command /path/to/the/file/CHOWN.sh with the argument "usb", it changes the ownership of my usb-key, which I mounted as /mnt/usb. However, this file should be run as root. That's why I entered this line in /etc/sudoers :

```
%hmis ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/the/file/CHOWN.sh
```

This way, I can run it with the "sudo" command.

Let's say the ownership of /mnt/usb is root:root:

```
$ ls -als /mnt/usb
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 13 10:50 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 15 2012 ..
```

When I run the command with sudo I get:

```
$ whoami
user
$ sudo /path/to/the/file/CHOWN.sh usb
$ ls -als /mnt/usb
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 eng eng 4096 Feb 13 10:50 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 15 2012 .
```

so the command works as expected. Please note that the user 'user' is part of group 'hmis'. 
However, when I use this command inside a python file, it won't work :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...
subprocess.call(["whoami"])
subprocess.call(["sudo","/path/to/the/file/CHOWN.sh","usb"])
...
```

In the stdout-stderr of the program, I get:

```
user
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/usb' : Operation not permitted
```

Does anyone have a clue of what's the problem?

Thanks,

Sarah

Comment: I am a rank amateur at `bash` programming, so this suggestion might be totally off base, but recently I also had a problem with a script which had to use `sudo` programmatically. The solution was to add `Defaults !requiretty` to my sudoers file -- normally `sudo` only works when invoked from a terminal, but this line makes it also work without one.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting remark. However, I tried and it didn't help. Actually I am running my program from a terminal (I call the command : uxterm -e python ...), so I think the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your python script more permissions.

At the console, open it with the command `sudo myProgram.py`, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't want to give my whole program root access. I just want it to be able to run some particular commands as root.